# Error while running very long SQL query with UNION ALL operator

Tags: sql, database, vertica

I am trying to create a data-set for Table_1 using UNION ALL and SELECT statements only. However, I get errors because I have over 50,000 UNION ALL SELECT statements. Can someone recommend an alternative way to do this? I can not use `INSERT` or `CREATE TABLE`.

```
Table_1 AS (
SELECT 'ABC' AS Abbreviation, 'lowercase' AS Value_Set, 'letters' AS Value_Set_Type, '123' AS Codes
UNION ALL SELECT 'XYZ','uppercase','letters','568'
UNION ALL SELECT (50,000 Times More)
)

SELECT * FROM Table_1
```

Comment: *However, I get errors* Provide **complete and unchanged** error message.

Comment: The Error is "The query contains an expression that is too complex to analyze"

Comment: Does your query includes 50k rows of string constants and have no references to the tables? And what is precise MySQL version?

Comment: Yes! It contains 50k rows of UNION ALL SELECT (data_1, data_2, data_3, data4). I only have the data in the rest because the columns are defined in the first SELECT. I do not need a reference table since basically I am doing an INSERT

Comment: And what is **precise MySQL version**?

Comment: Vertica Analytic Database v9.1.0-2

Comment: If so then you have added [mysql] tag wrongly - the methods which can be applied in MySQL are not applicable in your DBMS.

Comment: You may try to use naive solution. Provide your strings literals as one long CSV string. Generate numbers list from 1 to ~50000 (for example, cross join 4 tables with numbers from 0 to 14), and use SPLIT_PART() for separate values extraction.

Answer (score 1):

A `UNION SELECT ...` of fifty thousand rows is indeed a pretty complex statement.

Well, everybody and their dog can create `LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE`s.

So take the time to create such a one - and then fill it with a `COPY` command.

This way, the data is just data, and not an overly complex Sql statement.

You can put the data into an external CSV file, and use that file's name instead of STDIN, or keep STDIN, and put all 50,000 rows in the way I put them in for the example.

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
  id  INT 
, nm  VARCHAR(32)
, dob DATE
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

COPY tmp FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',';
42,Arthur Dent, 2021-01-22
43,Ford Prefect,2020-01-01
\.


SELECT * FROM tmp;
-- out CREATE TABLE
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 144.763 ms. All rows formatted: 145.332 ms
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 263.533 ms. All rows formatted: 263.542 ms
-- out  id |      nm      |    dob     
-- out ----+--------------+------------
-- out  43 | Ford Prefect | 2020-01-01
-- out  42 | Arthur Dent  | 2021-01-22
```

Alternatively - create a `LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE` with the first, say 1000 rows , and then insert the remaining 49'000 rows in 1000-row batches. Like so:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id,first_name,last_name,hire_dt) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
          SELECT 11,'Cynthia','Fitzmelton',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 12,'Prostetnic Vogon','Jeltz',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 13,'Stavro','Mueller',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 14,'Hotblack','Desiato',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 15,'Grunthos','the Flatulent',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 16,'Gogrilla','Mincefriend',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 17,'Wowbagger','The Infinitely Prolonged',TIMESTAMP '2016-10-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 18,'Wonko','The Sane',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 19,'Veet','Voojagig',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 20,'Trin','Tragula',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
;

INSERT INTO tmp
          SELECT  1,'Arthur','Dent',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT  2,'Ford','Prefect',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT  3,'Zaphod','Beeblebrox',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT  4,'Tricia','McMillan',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT  5,'Gag','Halfrunt',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT  6,'Karl','Mueller',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT  7,'Lionel','Prosser',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT  8,'Benji','Mouse',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT  9,'Frankie','Mouse',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 10,'Svlad','Cjelli',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00'
;
COMMIT;
SELECT * FROM tmp ORDER BY id;
-- out CREATE TABLE
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 268.707 ms. All rows formatted: 269.296 ms
-- out  OUTPUT 
-- out --------
-- out      10
-- out (1 row)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (1 row): 189.510 ms. All rows formatted: 190.855 ms
-- out COMMIT
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 126.164 ms. All rows formatted: 126.193 ms
-- out  id |    first_name    |        last_name         |       hire_dt       
-- out ----+------------------+--------------------------+---------------------
-- out   1 | Arthur           | Dent                     | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out   2 | Ford             | Prefect                  | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out   3 | Zaphod           | Beeblebrox               | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out   4 | Tricia           | McMillan                 | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out   5 | Gag              | Halfrunt                 | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out   6 | Karl             | Mueller                  | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out   7 | Lionel           | Prosser                  | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out   8 | Benji            | Mouse                    | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out   9 | Frankie          | Mouse                    | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out  10 | Svlad            | Cjelli                   | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out  11 | Cynthia          | Fitzmelton               | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out  12 | Prostetnic Vogon | Jeltz                    | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out  13 | Stavro           | Mueller                  | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out  14 | Hotblack         | Desiato                  | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out  15 | Grunthos         | the Flatulent            | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out  16 | Gogrilla         | Mincefriend              | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out  17 | Wowbagger        | The Infinitely Prolonged | 2016-10-05 00:00:00
-- out  18 | Wonko            | The Sane                 | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out  19 | Veet             | Voojagig                 | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
-- out  20 | Trin             | Tragula                  | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
```